# How to create a function that prints the number of identical values in three vectors?

Tags: r

please...can you tell me how can I create a function that finds the number of identical values in three vectors? And the result should be 2. (beause 8. and 10. are same in vectors)  The vectors are:

```
a = 1:10
b = 4:15
d = c(8, 10, 18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most efficient way is the answer by [@Dason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65887960/12158757). Below is another option with `mapply` + `rowSums`

```
v <- list(a,b,d)
sum(rowSums(mapply(`%in%`,list(unique(unlist(v))),v))==length(v))
```

which gives

```
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick and is more generalizable so that you could use it for 2,3,4,... vectors at a time.

The `intersect` function will take two vectors and only return the values that are in both vectors. So basically we want to iteratively apply that over all of the vectors - `Reduce` is a function that will do that for us.  Once we have the output of all of the values in common we just want to count how many there are so we use `length` on the output and that gives us our solution.  My solution utilizes the `...` parameter so that you can input as many vectors as you want.

```
intersectCount <- function(...){
    length(Reduce(intersect, list(...)))
}
```

Some examples:

```
> intersectCount(a, b, d)
[1] 2
> intersectCount(1, 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5, 1:6)
[1] 1
> intersectCount()
[1] 0
> intersectCount(a)
[1] 10
> intersectCount(a, b)
[1] 7
> intersectCount(1:10, 11:20)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Why this answer downvoted? I upvoted yours, +1!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks. I'm not sure why it's downvoted.  I think my solution seems like the cleanest generalizable solution. Your solution certainly works but I'll admit personally I find it quite a bit harder to follow the logic. As to the downvote - My guess is that maybe r.user.05apr was salty that I commented about the deficiencies of their solution? I could very well be wrong on that but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `aggregate`

```
sum(aggregate(ind ~ values, stack(list(a = a, b = b, d = d)), FUN = length)$ind == 3)
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)
a = 1:10; b = 4:15; d = c(8, 10, 18)
reduce(list(a, b, d), intersect)
# [1]  8 10
```

Comment: reduce needs to be capitalized and you have the arguments flipped.  They also want it to provide the count.

Comment: You're still omitting counting the final result

Comment: @Dason are `reduce` and `Reduce` different?

Comment: @AnilGoyal - Capitalization matters in R.  When I commented originally they didn't have the library statement.  So I'm guessing there is a `reduce` function in tidyverse somewhere that has the arguments flipped but otherwise acts the same.

Comment: Thanks @Dason for explaining